# Batch scripting for executing .sql scripts in a directory

Tags: sql, batch-file

We have a directory which contains .sql scripts to be executed one after the another depending by the numbering: eg the file names will be 1.abc.sql , 2.ter.sql , 3.wty.sql so on .

I want to develop a batch script which will reside in the directory of sql scripts and will ask for the script number to be executed and input will be like " '1' or '2' or '3' or '10' ". Based on the input received ,  script execution should begin from that numbered script to the end of .sql scripts in the directory.

eg if '1' is received as input then  script execution should start from 1.abc.sql and if '2'is received then the script execution should start from 2.ter.sql to end of all scripts in the directory  and record the logs of each script to a filename_sqloutput.txt .

The condition is : If any of the script gives any error message like column name incorrect , or incorrect table name etc. The script execution should stop immediately and further scripts should not executed .

I tried with the below code:  .

Need your help !!!

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.sql') do (
call sqlcmd -S AMRVSP000000318 -i %%a  -o"%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 

findstr "Msg" "%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 2>NUL
if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
    echo Error occured in script %%a

echo Please check the %%~na_sqloutput.txt for detailed error logs 
    pause
    exit /B
) else (
    echo Successfully executed script %%a
) 
)
pause
```

Comment: Use the `SET /P` command to get user input.

Comment: Do ALL the script names start with a number and then a period?  Basically verifying that they are consistently named with the same format.

Comment: Are there any gaps in the numbers?  4.abc.sql and then 6.xyz.sql.  Will there ever be missing numbers?

Comment: There will not be any missing number. it will be numbered from 1 to the last numbered script in directory